# Does VLC media player store the files or its history in a hidden location?

Tags: vlc-media-player, history

Does VLC media player store the played files hidden somewhere? I share my computer with a fellow student and do not want him to see what I have been watching.

Is the history or files of what's played in VLC stored or logged anywhere on the computer?

I want to know if there is a hidden file somewhere that shows what I have been watching through the media player, and vice versa, show what my roommate may have been watching.

Comment: Why aren't you using multiple accounts on the computer so you don't have to worry about information being shared? That's kind of the purpose behind having accounts.

Comment: Use a portable VNC/browser from your flash drive?

Comment: @Zoredache, That wouldn't work. The exe may be in that portable folder but it writes to the local file.

Comment: @Bart Silverstrim Because the "fellow student" is really his wife haha

Answer (score 14):

On a Linux system, there is a file `$HOME/.config/vlc/vlc-qt-interface.conf` which contains the entry named `[RecentsMRL]`, which contains the recent history.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows (7) the `Recent Media` list is stored in the `%appdata%\vlc\vlc-qt-interface.ini` file. Open it and look for a line that says `[RecentsMRL]`. You should see the list below it

Comment: But, strangely enough this file is written everytime you open vlc. Effectively, the recent media is written somewhere else and is loaded when vlc is opened.

Comment: Windows 11 also stores in the same place...

Answer (score 7):

In VLC 2.1.4 you will have to access the advanced settings.

1. **VLC** menu
2. Preferences...
3. <kbd>Show all</kbd> (button, bottom left corner)
4. ► Interface
5. ► Main interfaces
6. macosx
7. ☐ Keep recent items

[image: How to hide VLC recent items]

Comment: On Mac you may also need to manually delete, "/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc.plist".

Comment: Adding a note: If you do that, **all** the settings will be lost; make sure you uncheck that box **after** you delete the file, if you find that necessary.

Answer (score 6):

There is a "recently used" list that is saved by VLC. And there are two answers for your question.

The "easy" way you are probably expecting: You can disable the behavior by opening the Tools -> Settings dialog, selecting the "Interface" section (would usually be preselected) and deactivating the "Save recently played items" option.

The "hard" way you should consider for your own good: simply set up a different non-admin account for your roommate on this computer, set up a complex password and **never, under any circumstances, give it away to anyone else.** Better yet, use EFS to encrypt all data in your profile directory - just in case somebody manages to get an administrative account on this machine.

Comment: I'm using v2.2.4 on Win 10, and my "Save recently played items" option has been unchecked, yet I still always see a list of recently played items when I right-click "VLC media player" in the Windows taskbar on the bottom of the screen. So it seems like that option is broken.

Comment: Ohh, it's because Win 10 has a separate "jumplist" feature that needed to be disabled: https://topbullets.com/2013/11/04/how-to-disable-vlc-recent-played-history-on-dock-taskbar/

Answer (score 2):

All applications that store a recently used list do so within an `.automaticDestinations-ms` file:

```powershell
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\<name>.automaticDestinations-ms
```

To disable VLC's/other application's recently used list/jumplists:

1. Navigate to: `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations` 
    <sup>*(View: detailed | Sort: ascending date)*</sup>
2. Open a file in VLC/other application 
    <sup>*(Note what `.automaticDestinations-ms` file moves to the top of the list as currently modified)*</sup>
3. Close VLC/other application → Open the `.automaticDestinations-ms` file in a text editor
4. Select all: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → <kbd>Del</kbd> → Save changes: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
5. Make the `.automaticDestinations-ms` file Read-Only:

   ```powershell
   Cmd /c Attrib +R "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\<name>.automaticDestinations-ms"
   ```
6. Verify correct `.automaticDestinations-ms` file was modified 
    <sup>*(Open a file in VLC/other application and it will remain 0KB)*</sup>

   ```powershell
   PS $ Cmd /c Dir "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\9fda41b86ddcf1db.automaticDestinations-ms"

     Volume in drive C is System
     Volume Serial Number is xxxx-xxxx

     Directory of C:\Users\JW0914\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations

       2018.02.07    08:50     0   9fda41b86ddcf1db.automaticDestinations-ms

       1 File(s)     0 bytes
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When on Windows, making the file

```
%appdata%\vlc\vlc-qt-interface.ini
```

**read-only** [right-click - Properties -> Attributes]
will prevent to show any previously opened media files.
Update: Clear the played list within the app *before* making the file read-only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).