# How do I clear the "recent files" in VLC on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, privacy

I have VLC pinned to the task-bar. Right clicking on it shows a list of recent files.

I have cleaned out the Windows "Quick Access" history and also cleared the "Recent Media" in the VLC main menu. Yet, the recent files in the task bar still remain.

How do I remove them?

Comment: Have you tried removing the shortcut and creating a new one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does VLC media player store the files or its history in a hidden location?](https://superuser.com/a/1320768/529800). While that answer disables VLC from storing a recent files list, Steps 1 - 4 apply to clearing VLC's `*.automaticDestinations-ms` file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does VLC media player store the files or its history in a hidden location?](https://superuser.com/questions/287137/does-vlc-media-player-store-the-files-or-its-history-in-a-hidden-location)

Comment: I tried all answers in those links and none of them worked.